# How to unit test(jest) the content of on ready event for an electron app?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, electron

I have this piece of code to be tested:

```
electronApp.on('ready', async () => {
  const filter = {
    urls: ['*://*.company.com/*'],
  };
  try {
    session.defaultSession.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders(filter, (details, callback) => {
      details.requestHeaders['Origin'] = '*';
      callback({ requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    log.error(error.message);
  }

  start(electronApp);
});
```

I have created unit test for the 'start main process' like this:

```
import { App as MockApp } from '../../__mocks__/electron'; // This mocks partially electron module
...

it('should start the main process', () => {
  const mockApp = app as unknown as jest.Mocked<App>;
  mockApp.emit('ready');
  expect(mockApp.requestSingleInstanceLock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

It works. but I don't find a way to test that try/catch and the session -> onBeforeSendHeaders.

Any suggestion? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Finally it worked:

```
import { App as MockApp } from '../../__mocks__/electron';

...

it('should start the main process', (done) => {
  const mockApp = app as unknown as jest.Mocked<App>;

  const mockCb = jest.fn();
  session.defaultSession.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders = (filter: string[], cb: (details, reqCb) => void): void => {
    cb({ url: '*://*.company.com/*', requestHeaders: {} }, mockCb);
    expect(mockCb).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(mockCb).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ requestHeaders: { Origin: '*' } });
    done();
  };

  mockApp.emit('ready');
});
```

I also mocked some functions of electron library mocks__/electron.ts,

```
export const session = {
  defaultSession: {
    webRequest: {
      onBeforeSendHeaders: (filter: string[], cb: (details, reqCb) => void): void => {
        cb({ url: 'http"//some/site.com' }, jest.fn());
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Just in case someone has similar issue.